# Why is my String object not being set to the command line argument at index 0?

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to use arguments from the command line and I would like that value to be passed in to `constant` in order to be used. When I set the value of 'constant' to `22,48,44` and removing the `args[0]` I get the expected output.

When I provide arguments through the command line I do not get the splitted string. Instead I get this output:

```
//arguments [swisniew@d10319 src]$ java Regex 1,2,3

After the split
//No output on this line
```

And here is the code

```
import java.util.regex.*;


public class Regex {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    String constant = null;
    constant = args[0];
    String[] sp = constant.split(",");

    System.out.println("After the split");
    for(int i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(sp[i]); //This line is not printing anything
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your question? Can you try to explain it more clear. What ur expected output? how are you running the program

Comment: How do you run the program?

Comment: Edited question to make it clearer.

Comment: Theres no need to cast a string reference coming out of an array of strings--itd be an identity conversion. But thats not your problem, and without more info, we cant tell what is.

Comment: @Thomas My apologies. I have removed the true output

Comment: Try running as such: `java Regex "22,58,44"`

Comment: you _should_ however check `args.length` since otherwise you'll get an array-out-of-bounds exception if you access `args[0]` when no args are supplied

Comment: @mlewandowski I still get no output. The for loop is not printing anything.

Comment: I tried here and it works fine....

Comment: @Xoce Could you show your code so I can compare it to mine?

Comment: Your code returns the result: After the split 225844. If its not working on your side, there might be something wrong with your input arguments. Did you run it within your IDE with the correct arguments? I used it with the arguments "22,58,44"

Comment: What argument did you provide?

Comment: I don't understand. Why would it just be 1?

Comment: @StepTNT I see. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

When I compile your code, I get the expected result:

```
After the split
123
```

How did you compile your code? Did you use Eclipse or another IDE?